# How to retrieve all the defects under one particular workspace using the Rally Rest API's in C#?

Tags: c#, rally

The below condition is failing......

```
 request.Query = new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "All");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all defects in a workspace scope the request to it, and do not define a query:

```
request.Workspace = "/workspace/12345";
```

It is often better for performance reasons to bind a query anyway. After the request is scoped to a workspace, the query can be limited by LastUpdateDate:

```
request.Query = new Query("LastUpdateDate", Query.Operator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, "2014-01-01");
```

There is no standard State "All".
If you want to limit the query by State here are couple of examples:

```
request.Query = new Query("State", Query.Operator.LessThan, "Closed");

request.Query = (new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Closed").Or(new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Fixed")));
```

[WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) is interactive. Before writing a line of code you may test queries there.

Comment: requestjup.Query = new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Submitted").Or(new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Fixed"))
            .Or(new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Open")).Or(new Query("State", Query.Operator.Equals, "Closed"));///This query is always returning me max value 200, why so?If I have more than 200 json objects, will it not return?

Comment: Per documentation http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/Index.html max pagesize is 200. To make it page use request.Limit = 10000; or whatever number that is larger than what you expect total result count is.